# ZGC bad cycle and don't stop with all CPU in jdk17

Tags: java, jvm, zgc

I'm using jdk17 to run some app, at first it's all right, after about 12 hours correct working, suddenly the service don't response and the gc log show like below

```
Out of address space 
Force to lower max java heap size from 50G(100%) to 50G(100%)
Out of address space 
Force to lower max java heap size from 50G(100%) to 50G(100%)
Out of address space 
Force to lower max java heap size from 50G(100%) to 50G(100%)
```

the log before this seems no wrong, and this makes gc takes all the cpu
is there any way to debug this or someone meet the same question?

Comment: Could it be this problem? https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8276055

Comment: @JurajMartinka thanks for your answer，I will have a try